# Infinite chevron line

Tags: css

I don't how it can't be named in english - I neither don't know in french to be honest - but I need to design an infinite line composed by normal and invert chevron. It's seems to be called a chevron line.

Here's an example of what I want and I only need one line :

[image]

Here what I've done so far with `before` and `after` pseudo elements. Maybe there's another way that i can't think of. Right now i didn't achieve to display it as chevron, i don't understand how repeating linear gradient works for the position.

```css
.chevron-line {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  background: white;
}

.chevron-line::before,
.chevron-line::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chevron-line::before {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,
    #000, #000 5px /* black stripe */,
    transparent 0, transparent 20px /* blue stripe */
  );
 }

.chevron-line::after {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-135deg,
    transparent 0px, transparent 10px /* blue stripe */,
    #000, #000 15px /* black stripe */,
    transparent 0px, transparent 20px /* blue stripe */
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron-line"></div>
```

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is zigzag lines. Check this codepen https://codepen.io/zoerooney/pen/pvOaxR

Comment: @Phiter, thank you this is the exact term. I'm currently checking your link.

Comment: @Phiter , it works fine :). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with css gradient

```css
div.box {
height: 500px;
background: 
linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(225deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(315deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 25%, transparent 25%); 
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-color: #000000;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

make it thin like this

```css
div.box {
height: 500px;
background: 
linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 35%, transparent 35%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(225deg, #ffffff 35%, transparent 35%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(315deg, #ffffff 35%, transparent 35%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 35%, transparent 35%); 
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-color: #000000;

}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome because it do not use before and after, this is the easier way i think. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Now i'm gonna need to handle the thickness. Do you use SCSS, if we can discuss on it ... because i suppose that i need to play with the `25%`but i don't know why you choose this size ?

Comment: Okay, so i can set the thickness from 25% to 35%.

Comment: The edges look jagged to me, both in Firefox and in Chrome, albeit in different ways. It's smoother if you use an odd number (e.g. 101px) for the `background-size`.

Comment: @Thomas i created a scss generator so it easier to set the height and thickness https://codepen.io/Alvan/pen/YLqEMR

Comment: That's great @Alex Vand